# Как NavigationView добавить <item> программно?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-xml, android-material

По задумке пользователь жмет "Add account" делает некие манипуляции и после его аккаунт должен будет появиться ниже уже добавленного, как реализовать это в NavigationView?

[image: drawerlayout&NavigationView]

Answer (score 0):

`NavigationView` использует `Menu` для построения элементов. Для добавления нового элемента меню - необходимо получить ссылку на меню из `NavigationView` и воспользоваться любым из предложенных методов `add`. Пример:

```
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
menu.add("New Item");
```